# AFNetworking request header missing after being set

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-headers, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm attempting to set custom headers on a per-request basis using AFNetworking, but occasionally the headers will seemingly disappear after being set.  Below is the code used to make a request...

```
+ (void) getWithURI: (NSString*) uri header: (NSDictionary*) header success: (NSString*) successCallback failure: (NSString*)errorCallback dispatch: (NSString*)dispatchedId
{
    createManagerInstance();

    AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation = [manager GET:uri
                                          parameters:nil
                                             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                                 [RestWrapper succeededWithJson:operation.responseString dispatchedId:dispatchedId successCallback:successCallback];
                                             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                 [RestWrapper failedWithJson:operation.responseString dispatchedId:dispatchedId errorCallback:errorCallback];
                                             }];

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = (NSMutableURLRequest*)operation.request;
    for (NSString* key in header)
    {
        if([request valueForHTTPHeaderField:key] != nil)
        {
            [request setValue:header[key] forHTTPHeaderField:key];
        }
        else
        {
            [request addValue:header[key] forHTTPHeaderField:key];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Headers: %@", request.allHTTPHeaderFields);

    [operation start];
}
```

For 95% of my requests, they go through as anticipated.  Sporadically, however, some will fail and indicate a header is missing.  This has been confirmed by capturing the requests in question using Fiddler and seeing that the headers are actually missing.  Despite this, the console log of `request.allHTTPHeaderFields` always shows the headers in place.

The only other thing I noticed is that in general Fiddler reports the caching policy as "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate" for each request.  However, whenever a request loses the custom headers, it's caching policy is "no-cache".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're adding HTTP Header fields in wrong way.

You should add it before request. You may try something like this :

```
+ (void) getWithURI: (NSString*) uri header: (NSDictionary*) header success: (NSString*) successCallback failure: (NSString*)errorCallback dispatch: (NSString*)dispatchedId{
createManagerInstance();

manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:header[key] forHTTPHeaderField:key];

AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation = [manager GET:uri
                                      parameters:nil
                                         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                             [RestWrapper succeededWithJson:operation.responseString dispatchedId:dispatchedId successCallback:successCallback];
                                         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                             [RestWrapper failedWithJson:operation.responseString dispatchedId:dispatchedId errorCallback:errorCallback];
                                         }];

[operation start];
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue.